# ASP.NET Return Name Value from the first table if there are records of it in the second table

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I want to return into my view a list of car models but with their make names.

This is the method that's getting (In the VehicleModelService, implements the interface) all of the Models in the database:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<VehicleModelDTO>> GetModelsAsync()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Getting all vehicle models!");

    var models = await _context.VehicleModels.ToListAsync();

    var modelListDtos = models.Select(m => _mapper.Map<VehicleModelDTO>(m));

    return modelListDtos;
}
```

I'm guessing I can do something here, but have no idea what :D

Or maybe in the controller?

This method is then called upon in the controller VehicleModelController and I want to see VehicleMake names on the index page like

These would be something like my TH elements:

```
model.Name | model.Year | model.Something | make.Name where model.MakeId=make.Id
```

If you need any other information, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Decided to call upon the powers of the Interface of the entity I need values for.

Implementing Interface of the Class1 into the Class2Controller so I can GetAllValues() method from it and send to my view.

Thought there's a better solution, probably there is, but this is how I solved it!